# VB Net String to DateTime

Tags: vb.net

from string `dataIni = "2015/12/21 18:28"`, I would like to parse it into same format `DateTime`. I am using following code,

```
Dim dataIni = "2015/12/21 18:28"
Dim dataIniParsed As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dataIni, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

However, I am getting `"21/12/2015 6:28:00 PM"`. How to get desired format?

Comment: That snippet is some sort of partial.. If you parse it into a DateTime var, you are done.  Dates dont have a format; format is just how it is displayed (`dtIni.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")`) or stored as text

Comment: oh sure... Then I have dataTable linked to my DatagridView and column has DataeTime format. Once I do reverse operation, DateTime to String, it is formated as I desire. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have parsed the text into a `DateTime` you no longer have a "format" as a `DateTime` is a data type that just represents a time and a date without any particular format. It's not until you do a `.ToString()` or `Console.WriteLine(...)`, for example, that the `DateTime` is converted to a string.

Now, by default, `.ToString()` produces a string format based on your system settings. Yours is clearly producing `"21/12/2015 6:28:00 PM"`. On my system I use an ISO date format, so my `.ToString()` produces `"2015/12/21 18:28:00"` for your date.

You can produce custom formats easily though. Try this code:

```
Dim dataIniFormatted As String = dataIniParsed.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm")
```

This produces the string `"2015/12/21 18:28"`. Note that this is no longer a `DateTime` - it's a string - and also that `dataIniParsed` is still a `DateTime` (with no inherent formatting).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the code below to format your Date variable. You have to format the date to get the desired result.

```
    Dim dataIni As String = "2015/12/21 18:28"


    Dim dataIniParsed As DateTime
    dataIniParsed = Convert.ToDateTime(dataIni)

    MsgBox(dataIniParsed & " - " & dataIniParsed.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm") & " - " & dataIniParsed.GetType.ToString)
```